# Is it feasible to make dendritic crystals at home?

Tags: crystal-structure, metallurgy

I've become interested in the forms of dendritic metal crystals from an aesthetic perspective, and I'm interested in whether it is feasible (from a cost, safety, resources) perspective to create metal crystals of this sort at home?

Would the energy involved, or the cost of materials, the difficulty of controlling conditions sufficiently, or the general complexity of techniques be prohibitive to a non-expert/ someone outside an institution? Are there some metals, or metal compounds (e.g. those with lower melting points - lead?) for which this might be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single displacement reaction between silver nitrate and metallic copper will yield dendritic crystal growth of metallic silver. Normally, a copper wire is placed into silver nitrate solution. The reaction that occurs is:
$$2AgNO_3(aq) + Cu(s) \rightarrow Cu(NO_3)_2(aq) + Ag(s)$$